# Converting particles (Render Type: Group) to objects is not working as expected

Tags: particles, groups, instances, conversion

I have a *Particle System* with hundreds of particles. Their *Render Type* is set to *Group*. I want to convert such particles to separate objects.

I tried "*Make Duplicated Real*" and clicking "*Convert*" in the *Modifiers* tab. The result of both of these operations is **not** having hundreds of objects, but in both cases **just 4** which is the count of objects in the group from which the particle are picked.

What am I doing wrong? Or don't *Particle Systems* support converting particles which were created from a group?

[image: demonstration]

Comment: I struggle understanding what exactly you were trying to do. Are you trying [this way](https://i.imgur.com/GWivALU.gif) and it's not working, or you are trying something different? Please update your question with more information and possibly screenshots

Comment: @NicolaSap Yes, exactly that. Only difference from your video is that I don't get all particles as objects, but only 4 :(. Maybe it is a bug in my Blender version (2.79b)? Please, what version are you using?

Comment: Same version! Hope you don't mind if I try to edit your question making it more clear. If you can, add some screenshot or, better, upload your file (instructions on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: @NicolaSap Sure, edit away :). English is not my native language, so it's no surprise the question is a bit confused :/.

Comment: just to rule out all the minor things, when you tried to convert, were you displaying a frame in which hundreds of particles were active and visible in the viewport?

Comment: @NicolaSap Yes (I overstated hundreds, it's actually just 150). I finally got to it and have added a video showing it. I couldn't use the linked service - it refused to accept gif and mp4 formats with "You can't upload files of this type." (Linux, in both Chromium and Firefox), so I put it on imgur.